# AWS ec2 SSH timed out but still can ping it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

My situation is that i can ping my EC2 instance using command shell of my PC but i cant connect to it using ssh (putty) ... i was able to do that this morning , was trying to send some files using scp , then i lost connection , i rebooted the instance many times but i still cant get access using ssh , i can still ping it tho .**(i allowed all trafic in security group)**

[image]

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: What is your Security Group configuration for this EC- Instance and what is your Subnet ACL ?

Comment: As @Matthias says, security groups -- what is your ip address now? has it changed since the last time it worked?

Comment: my ip address didnt change since last time it worked , and as said in my security group all traffic allowed to all ip adresses : _all traffics : 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0_  and same thing in my subnet ACL

Comment: Do you check the Internet Gateway and Route Table? How you install ssh- daemon? What  EC2 Image you use? In AWS Console -> EC2 -> Network Interface create an VPC Flow Log to see Incoming Traffic.

Comment: If an instance is **Stopped** and **Started**, it will receive a different public IP address, check that you are using the IP address that is assigned to the instance (but this doesn't happen with a **Restart**). You can use `ssh -vvv` to show debugging information.

Comment: hi , i figured it out , that was caused by the firewall , after instaling mysql i activated the port 3306 but forgot to authorize ssh and http , even if i allowed all trafic from the EC2 console , so i just had to make a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems when you rebooted, Your Server IP is changed. You copied new server IP in PING. Now For SSH you need to use same IP.
So Steps for SSH will be

- Copy Public IP or use connect to instance option from EC2 Console.
- Check which server you created(Ubuntu server username is ubuntu,while for amazon linux-ami is ec2-user)
- Remember to launch your server in public subnet.

In case you have security group open to public, you should be able to SSH by above steps.

Thanks,

AB